# Is it possible to declare a module with JSPM to be exposed to the global namespace?

Tags: jspm, reactjs.net

I'm using ReactJS.NET to render react components on the server. To do this, you need to pass it a list of components on app start up (on the server). ReactJS.NET doesn't do modules though, so you need to pass it a bundle in which all components are public in scope.
The preferred way of doing this is by creating a separate local bundle that you can pass it.

In the documentation for ReactJS.NET (http://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html) they give an example of doing this with webpack, specifically with the expose-loader plugin (https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader).

Is there a similar plugin / option using JSPM?